# Can't find python gold badge in 'Select your next badge'?

Tags: support

I just noticed there's a python badge https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51/python

I went to my profile and searched for it in the `Choose which badge to track` setting, but could not find it.

Why is this?

---

Just noticed that the Gold and Silver sections of the 'Tag badge' show empty in my profile (can't add image, apparently imgur is down?)

Comment: You have to select to track tag badges as opposed to just badges.

Comment: You mean I should select `Track a tag badge instead` in the `Reputation` section? I did that, and I still can't find that gold python tag badge.

Comment: Do you have the silver python badge? It looks to me like you don't have the bronze one yet

Comment: I don't have any python badges, and I'm not sure how to check which 'tag badges' I have? Never noticed this was so confusing..

Comment: You can see your tag badges on your badges page in your profile, or in the tags section on your profile. It doesn't look like you have any tag badges right now

Comment: The `Tags` section shows more than 200 tags, but apparently no 'tag badges'.  The `Badges` section shows all my badges, and I'm not sure how I would distinguish regular badges from 'tag badges'. I'm still seeing no gold or silver 'tag badges' in the `Select your next badge` pop-up that shows when clicking on the `Next tag badge`  setting. Is that expected?

Comment: That's because it only shows you the level of badge that you qualify for. There's no point in tracking your progress to the silver or gold badge if you don't have the bronze badge. Right now it should _only_ be showing you bronze badges to track. For instance, I only have a silver tag badge in JavaScript, so I that is the only tag I can track a gold badge for.

Comment: There's also a small gap between earning the current badge and the next one being available to track - I had the same issue with Android today and found this question.

Comment: @Gabriel: except most of us can't see 'Track a tag badge instead'. So: only the subset who already have at least one tag badge can track a tag badge. The rest of us can't.